# Has the Dart lambda syntax for method an effect at runtime?

Tags: dart, methods, lambda

In JavaScript there is a difference between `m1` and `m2`:

```js
class A {
  m1() { return 123; }
  m2 = () => 123;
}
```

Here, `m1` is stored in the prototype (it exists in the object that represents the class) while a copy of `m2` is stored in each instance as a property. So the first syntax is better where it is adapted.

I would like to know if there is a similar difference in Dart for this kind of code:

```dart
class A {
  int m1() { return 123; }
  int m2() => 123; 
}
```

At runtime, are `m1` and `m2` completely equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dart, there's no difference.

The [docs explain it](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions):

> The `=> expr` syntax is a shorthand for `{ return expr; }`. The `=>` notation is sometimes referred to as arrow syntax.

The JavaScript difference is due to historical reasons and no sane language would have the same distinction between the two notations.